# SQL query to excel spread sheet use vba macro

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have problem to bring SQL Server data to Excel.

So anyone can help me out how to connect to SQL Server to use vba macro?
And how to make vba script to SQL query to Excel spreadsheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Office 2007 go to **Data** tab and then **Get External Data** you will see the optionto connect to SQL and in 2010 go to **Data** tab and click on **Other Existing Sources** and then select **SQL Server**. This is to pull the data into worksheets to manipulate directly.

***In VBA only***

In the VBA script editor include the  **ActiveX Data Objects** reference

Here is an code example on how to connect to SQL from VBA

> ```
> Sub Connect2SQLXpress()
> Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
> Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
> Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
> oCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB1; Trusted_Connection=yes;"
> oCon.Open
> Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
> oRS.ActiveConnection = oCon
> oRS.Source = "Select * From Table1"
> oRS.Open
> Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRS
> oRS.Close
> oCon.Close
> If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
> If Not oCon Is Nothing Then Set oCon = Nothing
> End Sub
> ```

To enable the Visual Basic editor in Excel read the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737.aspx) to enable the Developer Tab

This should provide a quick overview to what you require.